# Isomap in R Data are fragmented

Tags: r, dimensionality-reduction

I have a question please, concerning isomap on `R`, I use `vegan` package with a square matrix of distance : `isomap(Dist, k=2)` I still have this error:

> Error in isomapdist(Dist); data arre fragmented.

I did not understand what that means ?

Comment: When asking for help, please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). There's not always one cause for a particular error message.

Comment: Here is the square matrix of distance on google Drive : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzMljqv0BFFuMndSVVIyeENDTHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: And here is the line code ord <- isomap (Dist, k = 3)
Thank you

Comment: I've also found that increasing the value of `k` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Isomap will compute the distance between points using a path between points using only k-nearest neighbors - in your case, three nearest neighbors. If your data consists of disconnected components,  there may not *be* any path between points using only k-th nearest neighbors.  Depending on what you are trying to accomplish,  it may be good enough to break up your data into connected clusters and run isomap on each cluster.

I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter `epsilon` instead of `k`, and tune it to a good value in order to succeed.

```
library(vegan)
iso <- isomap(d, ndim=1, epsilon=0.3)
```